# I trying to use a sub query in MySQL, but is this the right approach?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables I need to pull from A,B,C (the data is not organized well)
I have used a JOIN on the first two tables but I an not sure how to proceed with the 3rd table. Is a sub query best or use another join?
 any help? can I use 2 WHERE clause?

```
SELECT DISTINCT `App`,`status`,`New App`,`Sunset` 
FROM `Table A` 
LEFT JOIN `Table B` 
ON `App (table A)`= `New App(Table B)` 
WHERE status NOT LIKE '%sunset%'
```

This is Table C, it has the request date I need

```
 (SELECT `App ID`,`Status` 
  FROM `requests` 
  WHERE `Updated` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 364 DAY))
```

Comment: it depends, you're going to have to use `EXPLAIN` to know for sure. [this might be helpful](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alias the tables when you join.

If they all share common identifiers, joining that's the fastest approach.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   a.App, b.status, c.NewApp AS c_new_apps 
FROM 
   TableA a
LEFT JOIN 
   TableB b ON a.App = b.NewApp
LEFT JOIN 
   TableC c ON c.AppId = b.NewApp 
WHERE 
   b.status NOT LIKE '%sunset%', 
   c.Updated` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 364 DAY)
```

Also, consider if you are looking [for `INNER JOIN`s or `OUTER JOIN`s](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/).

Comment: you might want to move codition    b.status NOT LIKE '%sunset%' to join, since other wise you are nullifying the effect of  LEFT JOIN